# How many ways to fill $n\times n$ grid with $2\times 2$ and $1\times1$ squares

Tags: combinatorics, functions

How many ways are there to fill a $n\times n$ grid with $2\times 2$ and $1\times 1$ squares? Squares cannot overlap or exceed the boundary.

I don't have much opinion about the question. Well, we don't need to calculate the $1\times 1$ squares as they are the squares that remain after $2\times 2$ squares. I think we might approach with functions. Is there a formula for the solution?

I calculated for really small numbers. Calling $f(n)$ for $n\times n$ square:

$f(0)$ (I think it would be $1$)

$f(1) = 1$

$f(2) = 2$

$f(3) = 5$

$f(4)$ (I guess it is 35 but might be wrong.)

Comment: This is [A063443](https://oeis.org/A063443), and $35$ is correct.  Not seeing a sensible closed form for it, but they cite several references and provide an interesting limit.